# Is it ok to canvass for tag synonym votes on meta?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I have proposed a tag synonym I believe is reasonable. However, I'm not exactly sure how users with the relevant privilege are supposed to notice tag synonym proposals -- this feature seems to be *very* low-key on SO itself.

I see a lot of requests for tag merging/burninating which are very popular. And also quite a few about tag synonyms, but most of these seem to have few views/answers. Is it frowned upon? Or simply not that interesting?

Comment: because burning is more fun?

Comment: Because even voting on a synonym requires rep in the involved tag, the actual audience to vote on any synonym is a tiny fraction of all the people that read Meta.  It's not inappropriate to ask here, but just don't expect it to happen unless you catch the eye of an interested diamond mod.

Comment: I believe it's okay, and on top of Charles' comment, try tag-related chat if you want to have better opinion (and maybe quicker response) from the users of the tag.